# PyCharm PEP 8: Continuation line under-indented for visual indent

Tags: python, pycharm, pep8

My code runs perfectly but PyCharm keep showing me the same warning:

> PEP 8: Continuation line under-indented for visual indent

When I click on this warning it takes me to an indent between these two methods:

```
def _get_text(self):
    return textract.process(self.path).decode().replace('', '')

def show(self):
    print(self._get_text())
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Is that the full code? I guess you might have a line with X amount of spaces but PyCharm is expecting a multiple of 4

Comment: I tested it in PyCharm, didn't get that error. You can click on the lightbulb when you click on place of error and disable that warning. Otherwise, I don't see a problem here...